# Create 4 arrays from parsed JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a parsed Json string that i would like to further split into 4 different arrays. I have tried using `$.parseJson('[' + data + ']');` which returns all of the data into a single array. More Precisely i need it to look more like  `catData = [Object, Object, Object, Object]`  Thanks for your help.

my data coming in looks like this

```
  [{\"LkpMasterID\":491,\"LkpMasterCode\":\"CAT INSURANCE\",\"LkpMasterDescription\":\"25\",\"Attribute\":\"Cat Values\",\"Dependency\":null,\"LkpName\":\"CAT INSURANCE\",\"IsAttribute\":false,\"IsActive\":true,\"CreatedBy\":52834,\"CreatedOn\":\"2015-09-15T15:25:46.273\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"UpdatedOn\":null,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"ProcessedPage\":\"Master.aspx\",\"DisplayOrder\":1},{\"LkpMasterID\":492,\"LkpMasterCode\":\"CAT SUPPLEMENTS\",\"LkpMasterDescription\":\"50\",\"Attribute\":\"Cat Values\",\"Dependency\":null,\"LkpName\":\"CAT SUPPLEMENTS\",\"IsAttribute\":false,\"IsActive\":true,\"CreatedBy\":52834,\"CreatedOn\":\"2015-09-15T15:28:36.2\",\"UpdatedBy\":56366,\"UpdatedOn\":\"2015-09-16T10:26:36.95\",\"IsDeleted\":false,\"ProcessedPage\":\"Master.aspx\",\"DisplayOrder\":2},{\"LkpMasterID\":493,\"LkpMasterCode\":\"OTHER CATS\",\"LkpMasterDescription\":\"30\",\"Attribute\":\"Cat Values\",\"Dependency\":null,\"LkpName\":\"OTHER CATS\",\"IsAttribute\":false,\"IsActive\":true,\"CreatedBy\":56366,\"CreatedOn\":\"2015-09-16T10:27:37.777\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"UpdatedOn\":null,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"ProcessedPage\":\"Master.aspx\",\"DisplayOrder\":3},{\"LkpMasterID\":495,\"LkpMasterCode\":\"SHORT-TERM CATS\",\"LkpMasterDescription\":\"30\",\"Attribute\":\"CAT Values\",\"Dependency\":null,\"LkpName\":\"SHORT-TERM CATS\",\"IsAttribute\":false,\"IsActive\":true,\"CreatedBy\":56366,\"CreatedOn\":\"2015-10-02T00:00:00\",\"UpdatedBy\":null,\"UpdatedOn\":null,\"IsDeleted\":false,\"ProcessedPage\":\"Master.aspx\",\"DisplayOrder\":4}]"


$.getJson('LkpMasterTable', function (data) { var catData = JSON.Parse(data)) }   

var catData = [
 {"LkpMasterID":491,"LkpMasterCode":"CAT  INSURANCE","LkpMasterDescription":"25","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"CAT INSURANCE","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":52834,"CreatedOn":"2015-09-15T15:25:46.273","UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedOn":null,"IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":1},

 {"LkpMasterID":492,"LkpMasterCode":"CAT SUPPLEMENTS","LkpMasterDescription":"50","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"CAT SUPPLEMENTS","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":52834,"CreatedOn":"2015-09-15T15:28:36.2","UpdatedBy":56366,"UpdatedOn":"2015-09-16T10:26:36.95","IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":2},

 {"LkpMasterID":493,"LkpMasterCode":"OTHER CATS","LkpMasterDescription":"30","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"OTHER CATS","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":56366,"CreatedOn":"2015-09-16T10:27:37.777","UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedOn":null,"IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":3},

 {"LkpMasterID":495,"LkpMasterCode":"SHORT-TERM CATS","LkpMasterDescription":"30","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"SHORT-TERM CATS","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":56366,"CreatedOn":"2015-10-02T00:00:00","UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedOn":null,"IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":4}
  ]
```

Comment: What is the exact raw JSON you get?

Comment: FYI, `getJson` returns JSON data, that don't need to parsed again

Comment: `$.getJson` should be `$.getJSON`

Comment: It seems the data you get is already an array with four objects, exactly like you want it. There is nothing you have to do. `$.getJSON('LkpMasterTable', function (catData) { ... })` should be all you need.

Comment: what i am getting now is catData = [all of the data] what i am looking for is catData [object1, object2, object3, object4]

Comment: What exactly is "all of the data"? Again, the JSON you showed has already the structure you want to get. There is nothing you have to do.

Comment: On the slight chance that you have encoded the data twice, i.e. a JSON encoded string that contains JSON, you indeed have to call `JSON.parse` again, but the better solution would be to fix your server side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkittell/xkfm932h/)

What you can do is use jQuery's [map function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to "Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items."

```
var catData = [
 {"LkpMasterID":491,"LkpMasterCode":"CAT  INSURANCE","LkpMasterDescription":"25","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"CAT INSURANCE","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":52834,"CreatedOn":"2015-09-15T15:25:46.273","UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedOn":null,"IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":1},

 {"LkpMasterID":492,"LkpMasterCode":"CAT SUPPLEMENTS","LkpMasterDescription":"50","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"CAT SUPPLEMENTS","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":52834,"CreatedOn":"2015-09-15T15:28:36.2","UpdatedBy":56366,"UpdatedOn":"2015-09-16T10:26:36.95","IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":2},

 {"LkpMasterID":493,"LkpMasterCode":"OTHER CATS","LkpMasterDescription":"30","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"OTHER CATS","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":56366,"CreatedOn":"2015-09-16T10:27:37.777","UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedOn":null,"IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":3},

 {"LkpMasterID":495,"LkpMasterCode":"SHORT-TERM CATS","LkpMasterDescription":"30","Attribute":"Cat Values","Dependency":null,"LkpName":"SHORT-TERM CATS","IsAttribute":false,"IsActive":true,"CreatedBy":56366,"CreatedOn":"2015-10-02T00:00:00","UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedOn":null,"IsDeleted":false,"ProcessedPage":"Master.aspx","DisplayOrder":4}
  ]

var arr = $.map(catData, function(x) { return x; })

console.log(arr)
```

The [results](http://screencast.com/t/IFmKsuKBHocw) of using map look like 'catData = [Object, Object, Object, Object]'.

Comment: What exactly is the point of this? `catData` and `arr` will look exactly the same since you are using the identify function. Not sure I understand the purpose of `$.map` here. The fact that the OP accepted this either means they don't understand it the solution or they wanted something very different than explained in the question. If you want to do a shallow copy of the array, `var arr = catData.slice(0);` would be simpler.